# Sorting Object Properties by Specified Order

Tags: javascript, angular

Looking for a way to order the properties of a JavaScript order by a predefined list i.e. not sorted alphabetically and not sorting the records by a specified property.  I understand this is not possible.  See below for example  of what i am trying to achieve

Essentially I have built a dynamic table in an angular project that takes in an array of objects and I am using the first record to provide the headings for the table, but i want to order those headings and the subsequent data in the table using an array of string to determine the order.

Currently i get a table with headings of "name", "id", "date"

However my data is displayed in Alphabetical Order as per properties i.e. "date", "id", "name"

Any suggestions on an approach i could take here - thanks guys

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzpbcb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I think you already did or know the solution. The data is in tableData. Also have another array of keys that will specify the order of headings. And as you did in the first *ngFor loop, iterate over the array of heading to render the header.. and the 2nd *ngFor loop to display data there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already did or know the solution. The data is in tableData. Also have another array of keys that will specify the order of headings. And as you did in the first ngFor loop, iterate over the array of heading to render the header.. and the 2nd ngFor loop to display data there.

This can be extended further. Create a grid component that will take an input param. Let's say gridModel and it will have two properties like below:

```
gridModel = {
  'header': ['name', 'id', 'date'],
  'gridData': [
      { 'id': '4640516b', 'date': '2020-10-15', 'name': 'Test 2' },
      { 'id': '4640516b', 'date': '2020-10-15', 'name': 'Test 2' }
   ]
}

<my-grid (model)="gridModel"></my-grid>
```

This model can be extended further by specifying for each column, their data type or if they're sortable or not etc. So your grid will become a re-usable component and you can keep extending the functionality of the grid and expose the input model of the grid to consumers. Further more if the grid exposes some event, you can do that too, like click on a data in the grid (hyperlink) etc.

It is also possible that you take only header as input for the grid to render it and pass the data later to grid (which will come via an ajax call). Something like:

```
 <my-grid (model)="gridModel" (data)="tableData"></my-grid>

 //after ajax api call, you can do:
 this.tableData = response.data;
```

In your stackblitz, the ngFor loop to show data would look like below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let tableRow of gridModel.gridData; let i = index">
  <td *ngFor = "let column of gridModel.header">
   {{tableRow[column]}}
  </td> 
</tr>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v5ga1q

Comment: thanks for the response, i don't think this resolves the issue.  I don't have any issue setting it up as a component and sending data into it.  I just didn't do it that way to show a simpler version of what i am trying to do.  I recreated it as a static component using your gridModel Approach and the values don't match the header as they are in a different order.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzpbcb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Let me fix the code you shared in your stackblitz.. will get back..

Comment: Please let me know if you're able to access this url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v5ga1q

Comment: I updated my above answer too.. to match your use case.

Comment: Yes that is perfect thanks for your persistence and prompt responses, much appreciated